# Obtener el valor de un parámetro de salida Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedure, linq-to-sql

Tengo un stored procedure que me devuelve un valor entero:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGiros_leer_cantidad_giros_pendientes] 
@idAgenciaDestino int,
@cantGirosPendientes int output  

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT   

set @cantGirosPendientes = (
  select count(*) from giros g
    where g.idagencia_destino = @idAgenciaDestino
      and g.idestado = 6)
END
return @cantGirosPendientes
```

El stored procedure funciona bien, el problema lo tengo en el código C# donde no puedo obtener el valor de salida de este SP, la excepción indica que no está recibiendo el parámetro @idAgenciaDestino y no encuentro dónde está el error.

```
public int LeerCantidadGirosPendientes(int? idAgenciaDestino) 
    {
        DbTransaction transaccion = null;
        try
        {
            int? cantGirosPendientes = 0;
            cantGirosPendientes  = context.spGiros_leer_cantidad_giros_pendientes(idAgenciaDestino, ref cantGirosPendientes);
            return Convert.ToInt32(cantGirosPendientes);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaccion.Rollback();
            context.Connection.Close();
            log.Error("NegGiros.cs:LeerCantidadGirosPendientes", ex);
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Dejo el código del designer: La excepción se produce al intentar ejecutar el 'ExecuteMethodCall'

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.spGiros_leer_cantidad_giros_pendientes")]
        public int spGiros_leer_cantidad_giros_pendientes([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> idAgencia, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="Int")] ref System.Nullable<int> cantGirosPendientes)
        {
            IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), idAgencia, cantGirosPendientes);
            cantGirosPendientes = ((System.Nullable<int>)(result.GetParameterValue(1)));
            return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));
        }
```

Agrego el mensaje de la excepción:

> "Procedure or function 'spGiros_leer_cantidad_giros_pendientes' expects parameter '@idAgenciaDestino', which was not supplied.

Comment: Aunque no se si tiene que ver,me choca un poco...por qué usas in int nullable para `idAgenciaDestino` ?

Comment: Lo uso así porque es una valor que puede venir así de otra tabla, tendría que revisar si en realidad es necesario que el tipo sea nullable

Comment: Intenté agregar de nuevo el SP al DMBL pero automáticamente pone los tipos de dato de los parámetros como nullables

Comment: Yo revisaría eso bien. A mi me da que obviamente el procedimiento almacenado no admite tipos nullables (sqlserver no tiene esos tipos) y que por ahí puede venir el problema...

Comment: Si se puede establecer un parámetro "nullable" en la definición del parámetro del procedimiento almacenado si lo declaras por ejemplo así:   `@idAgenciaDestino int = NULL`

Comment: En este caso no le estarías asignando un **valor** 'null' y no un **tipo de valor** 'null'?

Comment: En este caso se establece un valor `NULL` por defecto.

Comment: Puedes mostrar el mensaje completo del error? Gracias

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra el problema no es que en sqlserver tu puedas asignar null a un parametro de tipo int. El problema es si el tipo `int?` de .net es correctamente asignado como parámetro de entrada al procedimiento almacenado en la llamada al mismo. Yo no estoy tan seguro de que así sea, aunque no he usado linq para llamar a un procedimiento almacenado

Comment: Agregué el mensaje de error en la pregunta.

Comment: @Pikoh los campos de una tabla en sql server que permiten valores nulos y que en c# son tipos struct (por valor) como int o DateTime se tienen que declarar como nullables en c#, sino ¿qué valor tendría si en la tabla tiene nulo? Recuerda que un int? (o nullable<int>) es un int que puede ser null. Lo mismo pasa con los proc alm.

Comment: @Luis eso debe ser usando entity framework. Si utilizas ado.net, que es lo que yo suelo usar, no es necesario, yo nunca uso tipo nullables. De todas maneras, como dije no estaba seguro, gracias por aclararlo.

Comment: @Pikoh ¿y no pasas tus datos a estructuras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí se puede establecer un parámetro "nullable" en la definición del parámetro del procedimiento almacenado si lo declaras por ejemplo así: `@idAgenciaDestino int = NULL`
También modificaría la llamada `ExecuteMethodCall` para pasar un `DBNull.Value` si el parámetro `idAgencia` fuera nulo (`(object)idAgencia ?? DBNull.Value`)

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.spGiros_leer_cantidad_giros_pendientes")]
public int spGiros_leer_cantidad_giros_pendientes([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="idAgenciaDestino", DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> idAgencia, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="cantGirosPendientes ", DbType="Int")] ref System.Nullable<int> cantGirosPendientes)
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), (object)idAgencia ?? DBNull.Value, cantGirosPendientes);
    cantGirosPendientes = ((System.Nullable<int>)(result.GetParameterValue(1)));
    return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

Comment: Esa modificación me da error, dice que "El operador '??' no se puede aplicar a operandos del tipo 'int?' y 'System.DBNull'"

Comment: Cierto, modifico el código

Comment: Cuidado con esta modificación, los `mappings` se generan en automático cuando importas el modelo de datos, entonces, si en algún momento llegas a reimportar nuevamente el modelo se perderán esos cambios

Comment: Cierto, Pero es responsabilidad del desarrollador el uso de un gestor de código fuente (digamos `GIT`) o no para ver los cambios aplicados cuando se genere de nuevo el modelo de datos.

Comment: Sigue devolviendo el mismo error de que no está recibiendo el parámetro @idAgenciaDestino. El valor lo recibe pero por lo que veo no lo está tomando como un valor que corresponde a ese parámetro

Comment: Creo que el problema está con parámetro de salida, porque tengo otros stored procedures que no tienen parámetro de salida, sus parámetros de entrada son nullables y funcionan perfectamente

Comment: Voy a modificar el código de mi respuesta. Veo que no se establece el nombre del parámetro en los decoradores `ParameterAttribute`